# How to count number of rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
<?php
        $query="select usertable.id, name, username, dateofbirth, user_id from usertable INNER JOIN passbook on passbook.user_id=usertable.id ";
        $result= mysqli_query($sql, $query);
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["id"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["name"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["dateofbirth"];
            echo "</td>";               
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["user_id"];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }

    ?>
```

I am trying to display the number of books taken by a particualar user in the table. I have used the mysqli_num_rows query but it returns the total number of rows in the view. I want to display the number of books taken by each user as a table data. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean `COUNT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aggregate with a GROUP BY in your SQL statement (This isn't a PHP problem to solve, it's a DB solution):

```
select count(*) as bookstaken, usertable.id, name, username, dateofbirth, user_id from usertable INNER JOIN passbook on passbook.user_id=usertable.id GROUP BY usertable.id, name, username, dateofbirth, user_id`
```

Comment: I would add  `echo $row["bookstaken"]; `  to be clear  ;)

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) as count, usertable.id, name, username, dateofbirth, user_id from usertable INNER JOIN passbook on passbook.user_id=usertable.id